# Enthought's EPD example tutorials

Tags: python

I installed EPD fron Enthought and I am trying out some Chaco built in examples based on the instructions @ http://docs.enthought.com/chaco/quickstart.html. I ran into 2 [newbie] problems in IPython interpreter:

1.

---

```
In [3]: python lines.py
  File "<ipython-input-3-75ced467f885>", line 1
    python lines.py
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

Invalid syntax?

2.

---

```
In [6]: import lines
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Windows\system32\<ipython-input-6-8ce26194a7ce> in <module>()
----> 1 import lines

C:\Python27\lines.py in <module>()
      7
      8 from numpy import linspace, pi, sin, cos
----> 9 from chaco.shell import plot, hold, title, show
     10
     11 # Create some data


C:\Python27\chaco.py in <module>()
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 from chaco.shell import *
      3
      4 x = np.linspace(-2*pi, 2*pi, 100)
      5 y = np.sin(x)

ImportError: No module named shell
```

---

No module named shell?

I am very new at this and wanted to try out these examples after seeing the presentation video from Pycon 2012 by Peter Wang. I greatly appreciate any help on what I did wrong and what can I do to get it to work; I did not find anything on google or similar at the quicksart.

Thank you for your time.

Oli Long

Comment: Closed at request of OP: *I solved it by right by doing something stupid as right clicking on the .py file and chose open with python.exe. Thanks*

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1**:
Within ipython use `run` instead of `python`.
Example at ipython prompt:

```
In [3]: run lines.py
```

**Problem 2**:
Python is trying to import a `shell` module from *your* `chaco.py` file.
One problem: such a module doesn't exist.
To fix that, rename *your* `chaco.py` file to something else like `my_chaco.py`

Comment: Bernie. Thanks for your help. I tried "run" and renamed the file too but it didnt work. I tried right clicking on the lines.py and open with python.exe and it worked - isnt that crazy?